# Run function when a statement becomes true

Tags: javascript, boolean, dom-events

I have boolean variables that change after the user performs an action.

I would like a function to run when this happens.

Currently I have this:

```
setInterval( function() {
    if(window.username && window.password) {
        [...]
    }
}, 50);
```

This is not ideal and causes some problems by repeating things inside the `if` statement.

Instead of checking every 50ms, I would like it to check continuously. Is this possible?

Comment: Not really. You can modify the code that sets `username` and `password`, though, to dispatch some kind of event/callback instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any "immediately" correct answer at this point, however there are methods you can use to work around the issue.

A solution for most browsers (and IE6+) is available that uses the onpropertychange event and the newer spec defineProperty. The slight catch is that you'll need to make your variable a **dom object**.

Full details:

http://johndyer.name/native-browser-get-set-properties-in-javascript/

Also, look into ... https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS for a **non-dom** answer.